# Codeigniter activerecords

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new to codeigniter.

Im trying to send this query:

```
    SELECT * FROM employees
    INNER JOIN authorization ON authorization.Employee_ID=employees.Employee_ID
    WHERE authorization.role='Team Leader'
    AND authorization.Employee_ID NOT IN(SELECT Employee_ID FROM team_leaders)
```

This query is used to select employees who have a Team Leader position(role) and not assigned to a team.

I'm having trouble doing this query in Codeigniter's active records

My incorrect model code:

```
function teamleaders(){
    $this->db->select('Employee_ID');
    $this->db->from('team_leaders');
    $query=$this->db->get();
    $teamleaderid=$query->result_array();
        //get teamleaders id who are assigned in a tam

    $this->db->select('employees.Employee_ID,employees.First_Name,employees.Last_Name');
    $this->db->from('employees');
    $this->db->join('authorization','authorization.Employee_ID=employees.Employee_ID');
    $this->db->where('authorization.role','Team Leader');
    $this->db->where_not_in('authorization.Employee_ID',$teamleadersid);
    $query=$this->db->get();

    return $query->result_array();
        }
```

Pleas help me do this using active records.

I would greatly appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it Try,

```
   $this->db->select('employees.*');
   $this->db->from('employees');
   $this->db->join('authorization','authorization.Employee_ID=employees.Employee_ID');
   $this->db->where('authorization.role','Team Leader');
   $this->db->where('authorization.Employee_ID NOT IN (SELECT Employee_ID FROM team_leaders)');
   $query=$this->db->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM employees
INNER JOIN authorization ON authorization.Employee_ID=employees.Employee_ID
WHERE authorization.role='Team Leader'
AND authorization.Employee_ID NOT IN(SELECT Employee_ID FROM team_leaders)";

return $this->db->query($sql)->result_array();
```

Comment: Yes it works perfectly fine. But I would like to know if its possible sending the same query using 
$this->db->wher_not_in()

Answer (score 0):

Your `$teamleaderid` array is not in the format you think it's in.  It's an array of arrays, not an array of IDs.

Try this:

```
$teamleaderid = array_map(function($a){
    return $a['Employee_ID'];
}, $teamleaderid);
```

Comment: Wow, this also works. Looks like I need to learn more about arrays